# How to ignore a mouse click in Windows? (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, mouse

I am trying to make a program that sits in the background that can ignore mouse clicks - outside of the program.

How do I tell Windows this through c++?
I already made the program recognize the mouse click. Just not how to ignore it.

The reason I need to do this is because my mouse has a flaw where it accidentally double-clicks (or more) when I only click one time.

So basically, when the program register that I click with the mouse, it will let the first click through, but then disable that button (ignoring every following clicks) for ~200 milliseconds.

If possible, I would like to avoid using any external libraries. Only the standard ones that comes with Visual Studio.

Thank you very much for reading!

Comment: @bku_drytt I am sorry for not being clear enough. I just want to know how I can make Windows ignore mouse clicks. I know how to program, and I am going to make the program myself. I just don't know how to go forth to solve the problem.

Comment: @Nicky C I know that is a solution, but it would be nice to have such a program in hand anyway. It would also be nice to have the knowledge to do this if I need it in other situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [low-level mouse hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986(v=vs.85).aspx):

```cpp
// Variable to store the hook handle
HHOOK miHook;

// This is the hook procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if(nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT &msll = *(reinterpret_cast<MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam)); // In there is more context if you need it

        if(wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
            // Do your logic here
            if(letsIgnoreThisClick) {
                return -1; // This will make the click be ignored
            }
        }
    }
 
    return CallNextHookEx(miHook, nCode, wParam, lParam); // Important! Otherwise other mouse hooks may misbehave
}

// This is how you install the hook
miHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, reinterpret_cast<HOOKPROC>(&LowLevelMouseProc), hInstance, 0);

// And this is how you would remove the hook again
UnhookWindowsHookEx(miHook);
```

This code example can't be used as-is of course, but has to be adjusted to your needs and the individual parts have to be put in the right locations in your code.

Please also read the remarks section for [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx). You are probably going to need to create a DLL where your function is located (you can load it from your main code). The `hInstance` in my example has to be the instance handle of the module which contains the hook procedure. Also you *need to pump messages* in order for your hook to work correctly!

Comment: Perfect! I got it to work after a few different tries. Really love the comments as well. It made the job very easy. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, I realized only now that I had two mistakes in the code (there is no WM_L<OW>BUTTONDOWN, and msll wasn't declared).